# Change tr background-color

Tags: jquery, css

I have something like this:

```
<tr id='<%=currentRow %>' onclick="SetBackgroundColor(this)" style="background-color:Yellow">
```

When i click on a row i want to change its background color and i did like this:

```
function SetBackgroundColor(rowId) 
{
     $(rowId).css("background-color", "#000000");
}
```

but i don't know why it doesn't work. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Does anything happen?  Try using Firebug or some "alert" lines to narrow down if the click event is even firing, what is getting passed to the function, etc.

Comment: You can also create a CSS class and apply the class to your TR with the javascript.

Comment: See for a row click demo http://jsbin.com/ufihi3

Answer (score 37, accepted):

IE has a problem with background colors for the TR element. A more safe way is to set background to the TD's and TH's inside the TR:

```
<table id="tabletest">
    <tr>
        <td>testcell</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
$('#tabletest tr').bind('click', function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).children('td, th').css('background-color','#000');
})
</script>
```

Added: you can assign a single event handler for the entire table to increase performance:

```
$('#tabletest').bind('click', function(e) {
    $(e.target).closest('tr').children('td,th').css('background-color','#000');
});
```

Answer (score 10):

In jQuery you do not have to use the onclick attribute to assign an event handler. Lets say you add a class called mytr to each tr that you want to affect. Then you can do something like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".mytr").click(function(){
             $(this).css("background-color", "#000000");
        });
 });
```

And that will apply the event handler to all rows with the class mytr.

Comment: nothing happens..i use firebug to watch..it jumps where it has to..but nothing..still yellow row

Answer (score 6):

This will reset each row upon clicking a new one...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('tr').click(function(){
    $('tr td').css({ 'background-color' : 'green'});
    $('td', this).css({ 'background-color' : 'red' });
  }); 

});
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/aciqi/

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('#RowID').children('td, th').css('background-color','yellow');
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution is to probably use a selector for all rows in the table or addClass.

Example

```
$("#myTable tr").click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#f00');
});
```

or

```
$("#myTable tr").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the table row background color, try changing the table cell background color.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mytr td").click(function() {
         $(this).css("background-color", "#000000");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all..the problem was that in the masterpage i was loading the j`query-1.3.2.min.js` `before`  `query-1.3.2-vsdoc.js` and that's way it wasn't working..thanks again

Comment: Please select an answer so we know that you have a solution.