# jquery change tr background color to a specific tr in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some problem with this jQuery function.
I have a table and onclick I need change the background to the tr's.
And every tr has his own background color. This function change the background color but don't remove the class when the other tr is clicked.

HTML

```
<table class="steps_choose_pack" id="steps_domain_email">
    <tr style="float:left;" id="tr_ess" class="essential_tr">
        <td class="step2_tab_1" id="step2_domain_ess"><input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="field" value="essential" onclick= "showHide(['hide_steps_domain_01'],[],1);"></td>
        <td class="step2_tab_2"><strong>Essential:</strong>Domain</td>
        <td class="step2_tab_3">Qty: <select></select> </td>
        <td class="step2_tab_4">Unit Price:<strong> &pound;28</strong> Annually</td>
        <td class="step2_tab_5"><a href=""><img class="question_mark" src="<?=base_url();?>images/question_mark.png"></a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="float:left;" id="tr_clss" class="classic_tr">
        <td class="step2_tab_1" id="step2_domain_class"><input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="field" value="classic" onclick= "showHide(['hide_steps_domain02_01'],[],1);"></td>
        <td class="step2_tab_2"><strong>Classic:</strong>Domain &amp; Business email</td>
        <td class="step2_tab_3">Qty: <select></select> </td>
        <td class="step2_tab_4">Unit Price:<strong> &pound;52</strong> Annually</td>
        <td class="step2_tab_5"><a href=""><img class="question_mark" src="<?=base_url();?>images/question_mark.png"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="float:left;" id="tr_prm" class="premier_tr">
        <td class="step2_tab_1" id="step2_domain_prm"><input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="field" value="premier"></td>
        <td class="step2_tab_2"><strong>Premier:</strong>Domain, business email &amp; hosting</td>
        <td class="step2_tab_3">Qty: <select></select> </td>
        <td class="step2_tab_4">Unit Price:<strong> &pound;279</strong> Annually</td>
        <td class="step2_tab_5"><a href=""><img class="question_mark" src="<?=base_url();?>images/question_mark.png"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.steps_choose_pack').click(function() {

        $('tr.essential_tr').click(
        function() {
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('step_active_ess');
            $(this).addClass('step_active_ess').removeClass("hover_table_type");
        });

        $('tr.classic_tr').click(
            function() {
                $(this).siblings().removeClass('step_active_class');
                $(this).addClass('step_active_class').removeClass("hover_table_type");
        });

        $('tr.premier_tr').click(
            function() {
                $(this).siblings().removeClass('step_active_prm');
                $(this).addClass('step_active_prm').removeClass("hover_table_type");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You mean that the `addClass()` is working but the `siblings().removeClass()` not?

Comment: you're binding a new handler to trs everytime you click on the table ? doesn't make sense.

Comment: sorry I am not so expert in jquery

Comment: see here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821175/change-tr-background-color

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/YwBy7/

Comment: yes, but every row needs to be with a different background color

Comment: Thanks to @Brian I found the right way to develop the function!

Comment: @AndyCola I'm sorry, I didn't see your response or I would have adjusted the example. Good to hear you got it working though! You should probably go ahead and answer your own question though with a working example and mark it as answer. It will definitely help someone out down the line that has this same question (also possible that someone else might even take your answer and make it better)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is the best way but I solved like this:

HTML

```
<table class="steps_choose_pack" id="steps_domain_email">
    <tr style="float:left;" id="tr_ess" class="essential_tr">
        <td class="step2_tab_1" id="step2_domain_ess"><input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="field" value="essential" onclick= "showHide(['hide_steps_domain_01'],[],1);"></td>
        <td class="step2_tab_2"><strong>Essential:</strong>Domain</td>
        <td class="step2_tab_3">Qty: <select></select> </td>
        <td class="step2_tab_4">Unit Price:<strong> &pound;28</strong> Annually</td>
        <td class="step2_tab_5"><a href=""><img class="question_mark" src="<?=base_url();?>images/question_mark.png"></a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="float:left;" id="tr_clss" class="classic_tr">
        <td class="step2_tab_1" id="step2_domain_class"><input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="field" value="classic" onclick= "showHide(['hide_steps_domain02_01'],[],1);"></td>
        <td class="step2_tab_2"><strong>Classic:</strong>Domain &amp; Business email</td>
        <td class="step2_tab_3">Qty: <select></select> </td>
        <td class="step2_tab_4">Unit Price:<strong> &pound;52</strong> Annually</td>
        <td class="step2_tab_5"><a href=""><img class="question_mark" src="<?=base_url();?>images/question_mark.png"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="float:left;" id="tr_prm" class="premier_tr">
        <td class="step2_tab_1" id="step2_domain_prm"><input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="field" value="premier"></td>
        <td class="step2_tab_2"><strong>Premier:</strong>Domain, business email &amp; hosting</td>
        <td class="step2_tab_3">Qty: <select></select> </td>
        <td class="step2_tab_4">Unit Price:<strong> &pound;279</strong> Annually</td>
        <td class="step2_tab_5"><a href=""><img class="question_mark" src="<?=base_url();?>images/question_mark.png"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.essential_tr').click(function() {
                $('.steps_choose_pack tr').not($(this)).removeClass('step_active_ess step_active_class step_active_prm');
                $(this).addClass('step_active_ess').removeClass("hover_table_type");
            });

            $('.classic_tr').click(function() {
                $('.steps_choose_pack tr').not($(this)).removeClass('step_active_class step_active_ess step_active_prm');
                $(this).addClass('step_active_class').removeClass("hover_table_type");
            });

             $('.premier_tr').click(function() {
                $('.steps_choose_pack tr').not($(this)).removeClass('step_active_prm step_active_class step_active_ess');
                $(this).addClass('step_active_prm').removeClass("hover_table_type");
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<style>
.high-light{background:blue !important;}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('table tr').click(function(){ $(this).addClass("high-light");  });
  $('table tr td').click(function(){ $(this).parent().find('td').addClass("high-light");  });
});
</script>
<table class="steps_choose_pack" id="steps_domain_email">
    <tr style="float:left;" id="tr_ess" class="essential_tr">
        <td class="step2_tab_1" id="step2_domain_ess"><input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="field" value="essential" onclick= "showHide(['hide_steps_domain_01'],[],1);"></td>
        <td class="step2_tab_2"><strong>Essential:</strong>Domain</td>
        <td class="step2_tab_3">Qty: <select></select> </td>
        <td class="step2_tab_4">Unit Price:<strong> &pound;28</strong> Annually</td>
        <td class="step2_tab_5"><a href=""><img class="question_mark" src="<?=base_url();?>images/question_mark.png"></a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="float:left;" id="tr_clss" class="classic_tr">
        <td class="step2_tab_1" id="step2_domain_class"><input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="field" value="classic" onclick= "showHide(['hide_steps_domain02_01'],[],1);"></td>
        <td class="step2_tab_2"><strong>Classic:</strong>Domain &amp; Business email</td>
        <td class="step2_tab_3">Qty: <select></select> </td>
        <td class="step2_tab_4">Unit Price:<strong> &pound;52</strong> Annually</td>
        <td class="step2_tab_5"><a href=""><img class="question_mark" src="<?=base_url();?>images/question_mark.png"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="float:left;" id="tr_prm" class="premier_tr">
        <td class="step2_tab_1" id="step2_domain_prm"><input type="radio" class="myRadio" name="field" value="premier"></td>
        <td class="step2_tab_2"><strong>Premier:</strong>Domain, business email &amp; hosting</td>
        <td class="step2_tab_3">Qty: <select></select> </td>
        <td class="step2_tab_4">Unit Price:<strong> &pound;279</strong> Annually</td>
        <td class="step2_tab_5"><a href=""><img class="question_mark" src="<?=base_url();?>images/question_mark.png"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For more [Change colour of table row onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970634/change-colour-of-table-row-onclick)